# Google Sheets Query: Possible to Group / Order by without Select?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have multiple positive and negative numeric data entries per each day. I want to create a table using the **query** function, such that I have the following rows: Date, Negative, Positive, Total.

```
Date        Value
28/07/2016  10
28/07/2016  -0.9
28/07/2016  -20
29/07/2016  -30
29/07/2016  -12
29/07/2016  18
29/07/2016  -3
30/07/2016  7
30/07/2016  7
30/07/2016  15
30/07/2016  -1
30/07/2016  7
```

It looks like I could do three formulas with query function:

```
=query(A2:B13,"select A, sum(B) where B < 0 group by A order by A label A 'Date', sum(B) 'Negative'", -1)
=query(A2:B13,"select A, sum(B) where B > 0 group by A order by A label A 'Date', sum(B) 'Positive'", -1)
=query(A2:B13,"select A, sum(B) group by A order by A label A 'Date', sum(B) 'Total'", -1)
```

but the problem is that I have to select Date every time to be able to group and order by it. If I do not select A, the function returns #VALUE!. So the result looks like this:

```
Date        Negative    Date        Positive    Date        Total
28/07/2016  -20.9       28/07/2016  10          28/07/2016  -10.9
29/07/2016  -45         29/07/2016  18          29/07/2016  -27
30/07/2016  -1          30/07/2016  36          30/07/2016  35
```

Can I somehow avoid selecting Date for Positive and Total?
I know I can simply hide these columns, but is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try combining single formula with use of [double query](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OhGnZLzGeQOSA0hgyLfHBvDXIAp0E4aeH3vVlVILJeU/edit#gid=0) and [arrays {}](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en):

`={query(A2:B13,"select A, sum(B) where B < 0 group by A order by A label A 'Date', sum(B) 'Negative'", -1),
  query(query(A2:B13,"select A, sum(B) where B > 0 group by A order by A label A 'Date', sum(B) 'Positive'", -1),"select Col2"),
  query(query(A2:B13,"select A, sum(B) group by A order by A label A 'Date', sum(B) 'Total'", -1),"select Col2")}`

---

This construction:
`query(query(...),"select Col2")` will select only the second column of data.

and `{data1, data2, data3}` makes `data2`, `data3` to be placed to the right in a new column.

Comment: You Sir, are a genious! I hadn't realised nested queries were even possible with Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is any easier, but you could create a column C with =if(B2>0,B2,"") and a column D with =if(B2<0,B2,"") then fill them down. Then use:

```
=query(A2:D13,"select A, sum(D),sum(C),sum(B) where A is not null group by A order by A label A 'Date', sum(D) 'Negative',sum(C)'Positive',sum(B) 'Total'", -1)
```

Comment: I actually also did it this way, but was unhappy having to maintain it.