# Google Sheets - GROUP BY and ORDER BY on different column

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I got a table in this format

```
Name Datum
A   01.01.2019
B   17.03.2020
C   18.03.2020
C   01.04.2020
```

I get this table output from this query:

```
=QUERY(Anrufe!$1:$1000;"Select A,B where A is not null ORDER BY B ASC label A 'Name', B 'Datum'")
```

I am trying to change the query, so that it performs a group by. This is what it should look like

```
Name  Datum        count
A     01.01.2019   1
B     17.03.2020   1
C     01.04.2020   2
```

But when i add a group by and add a aggregation function to the select it still throws an error.

```
=QUERY(Anrufe!$1:$1000;"Select A,B, min(B) where A is not null group by A ORDER BY B ASC label A 'Name', B 'Datum'")
```

I want the query to choose the youngest Date, that is in the column B. But it seems that the QUERY-Parser forces me to add the column B to the group by. This results in the same problem, that i manually have to count the records with the same names.

Anyone has any idea how to solve that?
Already checked those links:

- [`Google sheets query order by SUM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987920/google-sheets-query-order-by-sum)
- [`Google Sheets Query: Possible to Group / Order by without Select?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689531/google-sheets-query-possible-to-group-order-by-without-select)
- [`Google Sheets query - Multiple “where” conditions with “group by” and “order by”`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481292/google-sheets-query-multiple-where-conditions-with-group-by-and-order-by)
- [`I got this message (CANNOT_GROUP_WITHOUT_AGG) from a simple query`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470434/i-got-this-message-cannot-group-without-agg-from-a-simple-query)

Comment: What is ` m` in your select statement?

Comment: In your output, it's actually choosing the latest (maximum) date in group C - is this what you want? And are you then sorting on this maximum date?

Comment: @ziganotschka `m n` means `min`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
=QUERY(Anrufe!$1:$1000,"Select A,min(B),count(A) where A is not null group by A ORDER BY min(B) ASC label A 'Name', min(B) 'Datum'")
```

[image]

Comment: When i tried this i got this error: `error parsing formula`

Comment: Sorry, you need to use ; in your locale: =QUERY(Anrufe!$1:$1000;"Select A,min(B),count(A) where A is not null group by A ORDER BY min(B) ASC label A 'Name', min(B) 'Datum'")

Comment: WOW! Thank you. Finally your code with a small change (max instead of min) did it: `=QUERY(Anrufe!$1:$1000;"Select A,max(B),count(A) where A is not null group by A ORDER BY max(B) ASC label A 'Name', max(B) 'Datum'")`